# Remove break statement

Tags: java, do-while

I need to remove `break;` statements in my code and I've run out of ideas how to do it. Can you please help me?

````
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double g = 1.62, v0, deg = 45;
        double inRadians = Math.toRadians(deg);
        double t, x, y, x0 = 0, y0 = 0;
        boolean hitTarget = false;
        boolean hitObstacle = false;
        System.out.println("211RDB121 Pauls Daniels Meija 11.grupa");
        System.out.print("v0=");
        if (sc.hasNextDouble())
            v0 = sc.nextDouble();
            else {
                System.out.println("input-output error");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("result:");
        System.out.println("t \t x \t y");
        t = 0.15;
        do {
            x = v0 * t * Math.cos(inRadians) + x0;
            y = v0 * t * Math.sin(inRadians) - (g * t * t) / 2 + y0;
            System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
            if (x >= 17 && x <= 20 && y <= 3 && y >= 0) {
                hitTarget = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (x >= 7 && x <= 10 && y <= 4 && y >= 0) {
                hitObstacle = true;
                break;
            }
            t += 0.1;
            } while (y >= 0);
                if (hitObstacle) {
                    System.out.println("hit the obstacle!");
                }
                else if (hitTarget)
                    System.out.println("the target was destroyed");
                else
                    System.out.println("shot off the target");
            }```
````

Comment: Why do you need to remove them?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You need to change your `while()` condition to also check `hitTarget` or `hitObstacle`. You also need to think about whether a last `t += 0.1;` before the loop is left is ok and if not, move this line.

Comment: What difficulty are you having deleting those statements?

Comment: Removing `break`s will change the code's behavior. What's the reason for removing them?

Comment: You also don't need `else` if you have a `break`, `continue` or `return` in the `if` statement. It's redundant.

Comment: I need to remove them because it is asked in my exercise. I need my code to work exactly like it is now but i'm prohibited in usage of ```break```

Comment: In my exercise I need to use do-while without ```break```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean run = true;
do {
    x = v0 * t * Math.cos(inRadians) + x0;
    y = v0 * t * Math.sin(inRadians) - (g * t * t) / 2 + y0;
    System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
    
    hitTarget = x >= 17 && x <= 20 && y <= 3 && y >= 0;
    hitObstacle = !hitTarget && x >= 7 && x <= 10 && y <= 4 && y >= 0;

    if (!hitTarget && !hitObstacle) {
        t += 0.1;
    }
    
    run = y >= 0 && !hitTarget && !hitObstacle;
} while (run);
```

Comment: Why do you create an additional variable called `run`? I don't think there's any need for that. Just include the condition that you're assigning to the variable inside the while, like `} while (y >= 0 && !hitTarget && !hitObstacle);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the breaks if you include, in the while, the statements you want to trigger the breaks. Since you are using the “if” to set a simple flag, you may want to simplify things by directly setting the flag with the value; also, if you mind about “t” you should place an “if” to be sure that is not gonna be modified when any of the “if” statements are true. The do while should look like this:

```
do  {
       x = v0 * t * Math.cos(inRadians) + x0;
       y = v0 * t * Math.sin(inRadians) - (g * t * t) / 2 + y0;
       System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);

       hitTarget = x >= 17 && x <= 20 && y <= 3 && y >= 0;
       hitObstacle = !hitTarget && x >= 7 && x <= 10 && y <= 4 && y >= 0;

       if(!hitTarget && !hitObstacle) {
           t += 0.1;
       }

   } while (y >= 0 || (!hitTarget && !hitObstacle));
```